# Why Does My GUI Login Require Me to Move the Mouse to Get to the Password Textbox?

Tags: 16.04, unity, login-screen

When I boot my Ubuntu Xenial Desktop system, it boots normally and displays the mouse pointer, list of logins, and a textbox for the login password, but then, at the very end, it brings up an Ubuntu graphic on the entire screen and sort-of hides the list of logins and password textbox unless I circle the mouse around like crazy a few times and then stop the mouse evidently in a certain place, at which point it displays the list of logins and password textbox. If I don't circle the mouse around or if I don't stop the mouse in a certain place, the graphic hides the list of logins and password textbox again; I can still type in the password to my default login, so the list of logins and password textbox are "still there" and the cursor is still in the password textbox, they're just not displayed.

This is really an annoyance rather than a serious system bug, but it drives me crazy a little bit. It happened in Ubuntu Warty Desktop on this PC as well. It only happens with my desktop PC, not my personal laptop running Ubuntu Yakkety Desktop or my work laptop PC also running Ubuntu Yakkety Desktop, nor did it happen when either of the laptops ran Xenial.

Many thanks in advance.